# A user is somehow accessing Pro features in the Free version

Tags: android, build

I have constants set up for my Flavor names:

```
public static final String FLAVOR_NAME_PRO = "pro";
public static final String FLAVOR_NAME_FREE = "free";
```

Inside my Activity's onCreate() I assign the boolean mUsingProFlavor a value:

```
    mUsingProFlavor = BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(FLAVOR_NAME_PRO);
```

In a clickListener created later on I have this:

```
if (mUsingProFlavor) {
     customerId = getCustomerId();
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomerProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("customerId", customerId);
                    startActivity(intent);
   } else {
        showProOnlyFeatureAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, mAlertDialog);
   }
```

This is the only way for the user to access CustomerProfileActivity, and yet somehow I'm getting crash reports indicating that one of my Free users is crashing inside of CustomerProfileActivity.

Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm not an Android person, but) [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370326/decompile-an-apk-modify-it-and-then-recompile-it) might be one semi-obvious way.

Comment: @Amadan The weird thing is he also owns the Pro version. I can tell because he's the only user who's causing certain crashes on both versions. If he already own it there's no reason to crack it. He could simply pass the APK around if he wanted to share it.

Comment: using ADB, you can start any activity of the app. Sobasically, user can start `CustomerProfileActivity.class` using adb command

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I guess he could be doing this, but since he seems to own the Pro version I'm not sure why he'd bother.

Comment: did you keep in app purchase for getting paid version ? , rooted phones can bypass in app purchases

Comment: @Redman They're separate APKs. Also, Crashlytics reports the device as not being rooted.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko It would explain this related issue I'm having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214960/intent-extras-are-not-being-delivered-on-a-specific-device  . If he's poking around in ADB the intent extras wouldn't be sent as normal.

Comment: Seperate apks ? then its even more easy , there are many external sites which provide paid apps for free

Comment: @Redman I honestly don't care if he pirated it. I just want to know how he's in that activity while in the free version.

Comment: `intent extras` that is *probably* the reason of crash

Answer (score -2):

```
if (mUsingProFlavor) {
 customerId = getCustomerId();
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomerProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("customerId", customerId);
                startActivity(intent);
 } else {
    showProOnlyFeatureAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, mAlertDialog);
}
```

Your -> if(mUsingProFlavor) is the issue here.
Since mUsingProFlavor is a String, you have to modify your if-check. Currently it is acting as boolean.

```
if (mUsingProFlavor.equals("pro")) {
 customerId = getCustomerId();
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomerProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("customerId", customerId);
                startActivity(intent);
 } else {
    showProOnlyFeatureAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, mAlertDialog);
}
```

Comment: mUsingProFlavor is a boolean. Sorry I didn't include the declaration line.

Comment: `boolean mUsingProFlavor a value` , `mUsingProFlavor = BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(FLAVOR_NAME_PRO);`. `mUsingProFlavor` isa boolean

Comment: if mUsingProFlavor was a String that wouldn't compile.  In Java you can't have a string as the expression type of an if like in C.

Comment: He can simply remove BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(FLAVOR_NAME_PRO);
.equals from the line and my code would work